# Gitlab-ee external url is not working

Tags: apache, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I installed gitlab-ee on my ubuntu 16.04 server hosted with AWS. I am not able to launch gitlab using the external url that is mentioned in gitlab.rb file. I have apache as default webserver. I used a subdomain as external url. But when i launch that url, it is still landing on default apache page and not using nginx to launch gitlab. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Apache and Nginx will probably try to use the same ports (80 & 443). The first started, in your case Apache, will start normally, but the second will not initialize properly as two programs can not listen together on the same ports.

Confirm with the command `sudo gitlab-ctl status nginx`. This will return the status of the integrated nginx instance.

If it is stopped, stop apache and then start nginx using `sudo gitlab-ctl start nginx`.

Comment: Worked, for me!:
`sudo service apache2 stop`  
`sudo gitlab-ctl start nginx`